# Using :daterange in Snowsight to show previous period

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible, using the :daterange built-in filter in Snowflake's Snowsight dashboard, to query for two periods - the one in the range and the previous period? This would be helpful so you could see the metric for the time period and the change from the previous period. I can't find any way to access the start and end date, so I'm guessing it's not possible. Is there a creative way to do it?

I haven't tried anything other than googling around to see if someone else has run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :date range in the query and use the date drop down which is beside the filter you can use current date -7 or custom range according to your equipment

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found is to change the date you're comparing to the date range by a set value of days, months, or years, etc.
For example, if you want the month before the date range, you can add a condition for anything that falls in the date range when adding a month but doesn't fall in the date range itself.

Something like

```
and month_add(the_date, 1) = :daterange
and not the_date = :daterange
```

Would be nice if Snowflake Dashboards allowed creating custom date filters to select just a single date.